# query the web by response headers and url

Tags: web, sql, search-engine

Do you know any service that allow you to use sql like query to find stuff on the web?

I read about something like it about 2-4 months before that gather information from the world wild web but I forgot about the name and I have tried to search for it without luck. (it was in a beta stage at the time and was invite only thing) It was a service similar to google that scraped the web and indexed the result with url and response headers from which you could query anything with a sql-like syntax: something similar to this:

```
// will find all png images on http://example.com

select (url) 
  from something 
  where 
    "Content-Type" == "image/png" && 
    "url" == "http://example.com/*"
  limit 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! https://mixnode.com
I finally got my mail invitation after a year or so

**edit** after trying it out i don't seem to be so impressed by it.

Answer (score 0):

Archive.org crawls the web. It may have an api.
The Memento protocol allows you to ask for a webpage as of a certain past moment